# Detect when user touches a cell in a table

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have some custom cells which are working perfectly. I have a background image on these cells. I would like to change the background image when a users finger touches the cell. It would then change back on the selection of the cell (but that can be done in didSelectRowAtIndexPath).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you allready have custom cell you can override id `touchesBegan:` and `touchesEnded:`

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    //change background here...
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    //restore background here...
}
```

Note that i didn't test this - hope it wont be just a waste of your time.

Comment: This time it did indeed slip my mind as I was busy implementing your solution. Apologies.

Comment: No need to apologise :) i was thinking in general - didn't know if you actually knew about this checkmarks or not. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Start in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to retrieve the cell, then you can change the content. It could be that you need `[cell setNeedsDisplay];`.